# Ubuntu 20.04 сетевая карта rtl8821ce

Tags: ubuntu

Проблема в том, что у меня сначала не хотел вставать модуль сетевой карты, и выдавал ошибку:

```
Чтение списков пакетов… Готово
Построение дерева зависимостей       
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
Следующие НОВЫЕ пакеты будут установлены:
  rtl8821ce-dkms
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 1 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 22 пакетов не обновлено.
Необходимо скачать 0 B/2 197 kB архивов.
После данной операции объём занятого дискового пространства возрастёт на 25,2 MB.
Выбор ранее не выбранного пакета rtl8821ce-dkms.
(Чтение базы данных … на данный момент установлено 181324 файла и каталога.)
Подготовка к распаковке …/rtl8821ce-dkms_5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.4_all.deb …
Распаковывается rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.4) …
Настраивается пакет rtl8821ce-dkms (5.5.2.1-0ubuntu4~20.04.4) …
Loading new rtl8821ce-5.5.2.1 DKMS files...
Building for 5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64
Building initial module for 5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64 is 
not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-11.1-liquorix-amd64 
(x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rtl8821ce/5.5.2.1/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: ошибка при обработке пакета rtl8821ce-dkms (--configure):
 installed rtl8821ce-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned e
rror exit status 10
При обработке следующих пакетов произошли ошибки:
 rtl8821ce-dkms
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Потом я удалил все ядра liquorix, на которые он ругался и перешёл на ядро - **5.11.0-40-generic**. Проблема исчезла минут на 20 и после этого опять началась. То есть к wifi комп подключается, но вместо значка wifi отображается вопрос, и интернет при этом не работает. Также и когда я раздаю интернет с телефона. Я пробовал переустанавливать драйвер, переключать антенну, убирал проверку подключения, но ничего не помогает. Можно ли решить эту проблему? (если нужны какие то выхлопы, то все скину)

Comment: Ну выхлоп говорит о том, что ты НЕ удалил кастомное ядро.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось очень просто - поменял dns сервера на google: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4. И теперь уже наконец-то все работает идеально.